# How could i create such query in hibernate

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Here is my query:

```
SELECT auc_id,name,MAX(amount) FROM `auc`
INNER JOIN bid
where bid.auc_id = auc.id
GROUP BY (auc_id)
```

Mappig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="DAO.Bid" table="bid" lazy="false">

   <id column="id" name="id" type="java.lang.Integer"> 
   <generator class="identity"/>
  </id>
  <property column="amount" name="amount" type="java.lang.Integer" />
  <property column="type" name="type" type="java.lang.Integer" />
  <many-to-one name="owner_id" column="owner_id" class="DAO.Users" not-null="false" cascade="all"/>
  <many-to-one name="auc_id" column="auc_id" class="DAO.Auction" not-null="false" cascade="all"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Auction class mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="DAO.Auction" table="auc" lazy="false">

  <id column="Id" name="id" type="java.lang.Integer"> 
   <generator class="identity"/>
  </id>
  <property column="name" name="name" type="java.lang.String" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I need to create the same query with hibernate.I need to get name form auc table, fields auction_id and max value of field amount from each auction.

Query as it is now : `SELECT b FROM DAO.Bid b INNER JOIN b.auc_id`
But it throws error thet first colomn of Auc table is unmapped in class Bid.Its true because this field is inside class Auction.But what can i do wit hit?

Comment: No one knows what your 'name' and 'amount' is.  No one knows how you have mapped the columns to your objects. No one knows what exactly you mean of "same query".  How are other supposed to help?

Comment: I haw provided additional info,is it more clear now?I need to get an array of objects which contains 3 fields auc_id+name+max(amount).

Comment: your original SQL already contains an invalid `group by` usage.

Comment: But myPhpAdmin says it  legit.As for now its all i need.Just to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

HQL is NOT SQL.  Joins in HQL largely leverage on your relationships to be properly mapped, instead of doing joining explicitly by column names every time.

Assume you have your models like this:

```
class Auction {
    Integer id;
    String name;
}

class Bid {
    Integer id;
    Auction auction;
    BigDecimal amount;
}
```

it should looks like

```
select auction.id, auction.name, max(amount) -- you may need to use max(auction.id), 
                                             -- max(auction.name) for some DB
from Bid
group by auction.id
```

(the `auction.id` and `auction.name` is an implicit inner join which means `bid.auction.id`)

Comment: And lasi am getting such error : Invalid path: 'null.name' [SELECT auc_id,Auction.name,max(amount) FROM DAO.Bid group by auc_id] Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
So isauction a property here or a class maybe?

Comment: your HQL is simply invalid.  Can you please help yourself and everyone by reading the basics of hibernate user guide first?  For the result, it is also covered in basics of Hibernate docs.  It is a `List<Map<String,Object>>` iirc

Comment: and, 1. please follow Java naming convention. It is not a good idea to name your field as `auc_id`.  2. It is better to model it as a relationship to `Auction` instead of as an integer which is the auction's ID.  3. If you don't need a ORM (from what I can see, you are not even making up a proper model), go ahead with plain JDBC or framework like MyBatis